# Custom UITableView Cell Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to make custom cell `highlighted` animation...but it does not work. Any thoughts how can I animate `.alpa` change?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"myID";
    TableViewCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    cell.selectedImg.frame = cell.contentView.frame;
    cell.selectedImg.image = [ViewController imageFromColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.55 green:0.95 blue:0.68 alpha:0.0]];
    cell.selectedImg.hidden = NO;

    return cell;
}
```

**TableViewCustomCell.m**

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (highlighted) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^(void) {
            self.selectedImg.alpha = 0.5;}];
    }
    else {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^(void) {
            self.selectedImg.alpha = 0.0;}];
    }
}
```

P.S. I will have a lot of `UITableViews` and they all will have the same cell style, so Should I place `cell.selectedImg` code somewhere in TableViewCustomCell.m? If yes, where is the right place?

Comment: For you p.s. question, use a super class. Like `BaseTableViewCell`

Comment: I am already using custom cell class "TableViewCustomCell". But where in TableViewCustomCell is the right place to setup cell style?

Comment: It depends, are you loading from a NIB, then it is `-(void)awakeFromNib ` it you do everything in code you should do it in the init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the code in

> - (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated

in **TableViewCell.m** with the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         if (highlighted) {
                           self.selectedImg.alpha = 0.5;
                         }
                         else {
                           self.selectedImg.alpha = 0;
                         }
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (highlighted) {
                          self.selectedImg.alpha = 0;
                         }
                         else {
                          self.selectedImg.alpha = 0.5;
                         }
}];
```

Comment: In your method just write the line first of all
[super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated]

Comment: your code is correct (except completion: 0 should be 0.5 and 0.5 should be 0) ! Thank you! I had a mistake.. Now it works.